# Get Built-In Windows Accounts

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to emulate the App Pool Identity window. Is there a way to fetch all the built-in account list similar to the app pool identity window?

[image]

Comment: Aren't the accounts you see listed always the same built in system accounts on any Windows machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The enumeration of all well known SID's (the "built in" accounts) can be found in [`System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.wellknownsidtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Those enums are used with [this constructor of `SecurityIdentifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/214122bs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you don't want a dropdown with 50 items I would just hard code the 4 or 5 you want in the dropdown and have those dropdown elements map to the corresponding enum members.

Comment: Thanks.Looks like i need to go with hard coding and then inferring WellKnownSidType from the selection

Comment: Is there a WellKnownSidType for ApplicationPoolIdentity?

Comment: No, this is because that line item does not match to a single identity. Each app pool is mapped to the user [`IIS AppPool*PoolName*`](http://serverfault.com/a/270074/32277). So you will need to look up the pool the site is running under then manually create the string that represents the credential and use one of the constructors of `SecurityIdentifier` that allows you to enter a string for the name. [See this article](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) for more information.